# Show that $\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}\sum_{i=0}^n \left[\binom{n}{i} \cdot \sum_{j=i+1}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{j} \right]= \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I have a hard time showing that that

$$ \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}\sum_{i=0}^n \left[\binom{n}{i} \cdot \sum_{j=i+1}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{j} \right]= \frac{1}{2}$$

Namely, I try to show hat

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \left[\binom{n}{i} \cdot \sum_{j=i+1}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{j}\right] = 2^{2n} $$

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you all.

Online demo: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cjo7zggjlf

Comment: What is $k$? Are you sure you copied the problem correctly? Even if you replace $k$ with $i$ you don't get equality.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I edited it. It is index "i".

Comment: I just updated the question in case there were typos. If you still think the equality doesn't hold, could you briefly explain why or give a counterexample for n? I range n from 1 to 100 as a sanity check. It seems like the equality holds.

Comment: Hah, thanks again! I was so negligent when translating code to latex. "i" range from 0 to n

Comment: I'm still not getting equality, even if you change the lower index of $i$ to $0$. Check here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4ddioz2ztg

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. It is a good idea to use desmos. Would you mind taking a look at https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cjo7zggjlf

Comment: I made a mistake in my Desmos link. I wrote $j+1$ instead of $j$. My fault

Comment: It is the symmetry which gives the result. Repeatedly use the identity $\binom nj = \binom n{n-j}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: What have you tried, along the way of showing this, other than the calculation? There are any number of common techniques to use on sums of binomials such as this.

Answer (score 6):

We have
$$
\begin{split}
S=\sum_{0\le i<j\le n+1}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n+1}{j}&=\sum_{0\le i\le n}\sum_{0\le j\le n+1}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n+1}{j}-\sum_{0\le j\le i\le n+1}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n+1}{j}\\
&=2^n\cdot 2^{n+1}-\sum_{0\le j\le i\le n+1}\binom{n}{n-i}\binom{n+1}{n-j+1}\\
&=2^{2n+1}-\sum_{0\le i'<j'\le n+1}\binom{n}{i'}\binom{n+1}{j'}\\
&=2^{2n+1}-S,
\end{split}
$$
where $i'=n-i$ and $j'=n-j+1$. Therefore, $2S=2^{2n+1}$, i.e. $S=2^{2n}$.

Answer (score 3):

We will show that $\sum_{i=0}^n \left[\binom{n}{i} \cdot \sum_{j=i+1}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{j} \right]=4^n$

Note that $\sum_{j=i+1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{j}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}\binom{n+1}{j}$.

Now consider the power series $(1+x)^{n+1}=\binom{n+1}{0}+\binom{n+1}{1}x+\binom{n+1}{2}x^2+\ldots+\binom{n+1}{n+1}x^{n+1}$. We have that the partial sum $\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}\binom{n+1}{j}$ is the coefficient of $x^{n-i}$ in $\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}}{1-x}$.

Now going back to our original sum, we can extend the index to infinity to get that this is equivalent to
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \binom{n}{i}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{j}$$
Since $\binom{n}{i}$ is the coefficient of $x^i$ in $(1+x)^n$ and $\sum_{j=i+1}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{j}$ is the coefficient of $x^{n-i}$ in $\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}}{1-x}$, this cauchy product is the coefficient of $x^n$ in
$$\frac{(1+x)^{2n+1}}{1-x}$$
which is
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{2n+1}{i}$$
We can easily verify that this is just half of $\sum_{i=0}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{i}=2^{2n+1}$, which is $2^{2n}=\boxed{4^n}$